# NodeJS jsonwebtoken gets stuck on sign

Tags: node.js, express, json-web-token

I'm trying to generate a json web token using the jsonwebtoken package and express.

This is the route I'm using.

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
req.session.destroy();
var email = req.body.email;
var password = req.body.password;

if(!email || !password) {
    res.status(401).end('Incorrect username or password.');
}
else {
    userBackend.getUserByEmail(email)
        .then(function(user) {
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
                delete user.password;

                console.log('start signing');
                var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                    expiresInMinutes: 480 // expires in 8 hours
                });
                console.log(token);
                res.json({success: true, user: user, token: token});
            }
            else {
                res.status(401).end('Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        })
        .catch(function(reason) {
            res.status(401).end(reason);
        });
}
});
```

This logs the first "start signing"  log, but it gets stucks after that and won't display the second one.
After a while(2 minutes or so) it will return an [object ProgressEvent] but won't display the second log or the token.

I'm using express 4.13.14 and Windows 10.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could try `jwt.sign({ id: user.id, email: user.email, ...}, ...)` instead of `jwt.sign(user, ...)`. Backend-returned models can be rather large with all the getters and setters and recursive objects, so try to minimize the data you are trying to sign. If it's a Mongo document, you can try `user.toJSON()` or `user.toObject()` or even `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))`.